# Reading value of Enums in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I'm currently playing around with Enums in C# and I got an issue which I can't fix. I tried to "google" around, but I haven't found anything solid and fast.

I have an Enum, which looks like that:

```
public enum Test {
   Hello = 1234,
   AnotherValue = 382
}
```

Looks legit so far. Now for testing purpose I tried the following thing:

```
int ToCheck = 382;
if(ToCheck == Test.Hello) { ... } // <-- that is the part which won't work.
```

How does it have to look correctly?

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(ToCheck == (int)Test.Hello)
```

or

```
if((Test)ToCheck == Test.Hello)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was browsing more around and found that casting (int) on it works.
So the solution is:

```
if(ToCheck == (int) Test.Hello) { ... }
```

Sorry! I hope this might help anyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
if(ToCheck == (int)Test.Hello) { ... }
```